# values of input tag are transferred null into database

Tags: c#, html, mysql, asp.net

here is some with my project. i want to add review form but in html form cause i already used server side for another reason.
here is html code:

```
<form id="modal_feedback" method="POST" action="#" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<p><label>Your Name<strong>*</strong><br>
<input runat="server" id="rvwname" type="text" autofocus required size="48" name="name" value=""></label></p>
<p><label>Email Address<strong></strong><br>
<input runat="server" id="rvwemail" type="email" title="Please enter a valid email address" size="48" name="email" value=""></label></p>
<p><label>Contact Number:*<br>
<input runat="server" id="rvwno" type="text"  required size="48" name="contact" value=""></label></p>
<p><label>Message:<strong>*</strong><br>
<textarea runat="server" id="rvwmsg" required name="message" cols="48" rows="8"></textarea></label></p>
<p> <input runat="server" type="button" id="rvwsubmit" name="feedbackForm" value="Send" onserverclick="rvwsubmits" /> </p>
</form>

</div> <!-- #modal_window -->
</div> <!-- #modal_wrapper -->
```

and back end code of c# is:

```
protected void rvwsubmits(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string a = rvwname.Value;
    string b = rvwno.Value;
    string c = rvwemail.Value;
    string d = rvwmsg.Value;
    string cnn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString;
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(cnn);
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into ab_db.rvw(rvw_name,rvw_no,rvw_email,rvw_msg) values('" + a + "','" + b + "','" + c + "','" + d + "')", con);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

}
```

Comment: this is name. in input tag

Comment: here my html code is not appearing even i used code segment

Comment: Did you check if the connection is proper ?

Comment: yes ,connection is success full but all fields are entered null in database, how? :(

Comment: Keep break point and debug and check if a-d have the values you want ?

Comment: i check it already but all values are null.

Comment: You should try referring to Text property, not Value!

Comment: but there is no any property like text. how can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having

```
value=""
```

for all the fields

Try this

```
value="@Request.Form["name"]"
value="@Request.Form["email"]"
```